# How can I make my program alert the user if there is text on the page?

Tags: vb6

In VB6, I want to make a msg box pop up if the word ERROR: appears on the webpage. If anyone could link me to a website or just help we out, that would be great.

Comment: vb6 and webpage ?? can you give more detail on you problem. You have a vb6 software that load webpage and you want to scan the source ??

Answer (score 2):

Please sample code below:

```
URL = "www.yoursite.com"
Set http = CreateObject("Microsoft.XmlHttp")
http.open "GET", URL, FALSE
http.send ""
IF InStr(http.responseText, "ERROR:") > 0 THEN
    MsgBox "Some error occurred"
END IF
```